# PowerShell: How to change table headers in loop?

Tags: powershell

I want to collect data remotely and adapt the table headers later with the help of an xml-file. This should happen in a loop, looking like that:

```
foreach($tableheader in $table) {
  $table.$tableheader = $xmlFile.$tableheader
}
```

Amongst others I tried the following:

```
$x = 0
$sitesonfig = Get-ConfigSite -AdminAddress localhost  
foreach($Prop in ($siteconfig |get-member -MemberType Property | select -Property name))
{
 $x += 1; 
 $siteconfig = $siteconfig | Select-Object  * | format-table @{l="Smile$x";e={$_.$Prop}}
}
```

Yes, I know this looks silly, but I've got really no idea, how to change the headers one by one without listing each time all the other headers, too.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a loop to create the header map that you pass into Format-Table.

Here is your second example modified to demonstrate this concept.  You should be able to adapt this to grab the header info from your XML file.

```
$x = 0
$siteconfig = Get-ConfigSite -AdminAddress localhost  

$headerMap = @()
foreach($Prop in ($siteconfig |get-member -MemberType Property | select -ExpandProperty name))
{
 $x += 1; 
 $headerMap += @{
        l="Smile$x";
        e={ $_.$Prop }.GetNewClosure()
    }
}
$siteconfig | Format-Table $headerMap
```

**Important Points**

1. `Select -Property name` needed to be changed to `Select -ExpandProperty name`.  The reason for this is that `Select-Object` in PowerShell will return an object filtered down to the selected member but you need a string for grabbing the property value by name.  The `-ExpandProperty` parameter will expand this to be the string value instead.
2. The expression block needs `GetNewClosure()` called on it to capture the value of `$Prop` at the time of script block creation versus at the time of calling.  This will probably be a little confusing if you are new to the concept of closures and PowerShell's scoping rules.  Without this, due to PowerShell's scoping rules, `$Prop` will evaluate to the value of `$Prop` at the time it is used by `Format-Table`.  By calling `GetNewClosure()`, the value of `$Prop` is captured when `GetNewClosure()` is called which is what we want in this case.